# ApplySymbologyFromLayer on ArcGIS Pro not working?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-pro

I created a python tool on Pro with the following code, and manage to run it without any errors or warnings. However, I do not see any changes on my layer:

```py
workspace = "C:\whatever.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
ref_lyrx = r"C:\SimbologyIwant.lyrx"
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
map = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]
layers = map.listLayers()[0]
layers2 = map.listLayers()[1]
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layers2, layers)
```

I also changed the last line to this, but no results

```py
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layers2, ref_lyrx)
```

Is my code expected to work?

Comment: Are you running the script in ArcGIS Pro or as a stand-alone script?

Comment: I created a script tool with that code. 

Forgot to mention, but the code works without any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the layer symbology you need to save the project.

`aprx.save ()`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its not that simple, I could only manage to make it work with the project closed (running the tool in a unrelated project). I hope that there is a more straightforward way to do it.